# Warning linting is disabled for this query in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I want to run about 3000 update in phpmyadmin but get warning linting is disabled for this query. The query us like this

```
UPDATE `oc_product` SET minimum = '24' WHERE product_id = '71';
UPDATE `oc_product` SET minimum = '304' WHERE product_id = '72';
UPDATE `oc_product` SET minimum = '38' WHERE product_id = '74';
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? maybe make the query in to one query?

Answer (score 0):

I think your linter is just saying "You pasted way too much stuff, I'm not going to check it all because it would be too slow.".

As the linter is just a syntax checker, it's not necessary to run the query. It just helps spot mistakes before you run the query, or in this case, 3000+ queries.

The "faster" way to do this is probably to make a `TEMPORARY` table, insert those mappings in there, then `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` against that table.

Comment: when I run the script it return zero result.
I don't understand about making temporary table. Could you please give me link or example? thanks